# RAML retrieve baseUri value

Tags: api-design, raml

I would like to avoid hardcoding everytime base uri in specification and use defined one in the root is there any way to achieve it, for example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Some Service
version: v1
baseUri: https://example.com
/test:
  post:
   responses:
      201:
        headers:
          Location:
            type: string
            example: https://example.com/v1/test/291 # here i would like to retrieve https://example.com/v1/ from root where I've already defined it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

You can specify the baseUri at the root of the document. It then applies to all resources.

See: 
https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#the-root-of-the-document